# Play 2: How to parse a dynamic list of form inputs in Scala controller?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a form where the number of input fields is dynamic.

How can these input fields be mapped with a play form? Let's say, the name of each input tag is 'foo_x' where x is an integer that is incremented each time a new input field is dynamically created on the client side. Is there any automatic mapping in Play available or do I have to do this 'by hand' and if so, how can this be done?

Comment: Ups. Forgot to mention. I use Scala.

Comment: In such case somebody else will help you, in Java I'd suggest DynamicForm class, but as far as I know it's not available in the Scala's API :)

Comment: Did you try to use forms with Optional values ? http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/ScalaForms

Comment: thx for hint. Maybe using "repeated values" could be the solution.

Comment: Definitively `seq` is the solution

Comment: `repeated values` solves the problem. Sample application "Forms" from Play 2 Samples shows how to do:  http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/Samples

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See "Repeated values" in the [Play2 Documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/ScalaForms).

You can have these mapped into a List automatically provided you follow the naming convention.

Comment: The example in the documentation is for a `List<String>`. What if the dynamic input fields are for a custom object? For instance, what if you wanted a dynamic form for `List<Circle>` and the `Circle` class has two instance variables, `int radius` and `String name`?

Answer (score 8):

As Brian mentioned, the Play documentation has an example of repeated values that should suit your needs.

Also, bear in mind that you can nest mapping definitions. As an example, I have something like the following:

```
val editUserForm: Form[User] = Form(
    mapping(
        "username" -> text(minLength = 4, maxLength = 50),
        "emails" -> list(optional(email)).verifying(Messages("error.mandatoryEmail"), e => e.size > 0),
        "urls" -> list(text(maxLength = 255)),
        {
            // Binding: Create a User from the mapping result
            (username, emails, urls) => {
              // Here, emails is a List[Option[String]] 
              // and urls is a List[String]
            }
        } {
            // Unbinding: Create the mapping values from an existing User value
            user => Some(user.username, 
                        user.emails.map(e => Some(e.email)), 
                        user.urls.map(_.url))
        }
    )
```

There's quite a bit happening there, but the important bit that I wanted to show is that I'm nesting list with optional with email, and verifying that the list has at least one non-empty element - effectively forcing the user to enter at least one element in the list.

Hope this helps.